# Find the times an object has the maximum value in Rstudio

Tags: r, max, apply

I have an object with values of how many votes each politic party has in each location of a country (950 locations and 8 parties).

I would like to know how many times a party WINS (how many times it gets more votes than the others).

Comment: You can use [`aggregate()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.6.2/topics/aggregate)

Comment: Ok, the object is a list, and inside the parties are integers. How should I compute that?

Comment: Could you post some sample data in your question?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant solution but one that seems to work.

**DATA**:

```
set.seed(111)
party <- rep(LETTERS[1:2], 5)
location <- c(rep("a",2), rep("b",2),rep("c",2),rep("d",2),rep("e",2))
votes <- sample(1:100000, 10)
df <- data.frame(party, location, votes)
```

**STEP 1**: identify most votes cast by location using `aggregate`:

```
most_votes <- aggregate(votes ~ location, data = df, max)
```

**STEP 2**: match votes in `most_votes`to votes in `df`and assign label such as `wins`to identify party with most votes:

```
df$winner <- ifelse(df$votes[match(df$votes,most_votes$votes)], "wins", NA)
```

**RESULT**:

```
df
   party location votes winner
1      A        a 99283   wins
2      B        a 27417   <NA>
3      A        b 34885   wins
4      B        b  6140   <NA>
5      A        c  3117   <NA>
6      B        c 29258   wins
7      A        d 84249   <NA>
8      B        d 90875   wins
9      A        e 86641   wins
10     B        e 18567   <NA>
```